# Swiss visa query

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland

I have been issued a Swiss visa with one  entry. I had requested for multiple entries. I will be entering Zurich on the first day of the visa. I also will be visiting the UK, Italy and France by train. Can I enter Switzerland again after visiting the UK, France and Italy?

Answer (score 3):

No. Since it is only a single entry visa, you cannot re-enter the Schengen region once you leave it. Going to the UK would mean leaving Schengen.

Answer (score 3):

**No.** You can visit France and Italy, which are also within the Schengen zone. There is generally no border control between those countries, and if there is a spot check, you will pass through with no problem.

The UK is not in Schengen, and when you leave the continent to go there, your single-entry visa will be canceled and you will be unable to get back in.

Comment: I thought the land bridge between Continental Europe and the island of Great Britain had disappeared long ago, but I would be glad to be corrected.

Comment: @HankyPanky "the continent" is commonly used to differentiate the European mainland from the islands of Great Britain and Ireland.